# Related with count, max and group by

Tags: sql, group-by, amazon-redshift

Here is my table. I am trying to get distinct person distinct fruit based on maximum number of fruits he has.

**`persons   |   fruits`**
   `David         apple`
   `David         apple`
   `David         apple`
   `David         banana`
   `David         orange`
   `Sam           apple`
   `Sam           banana`
   `Sam           orange`
   `Sam           orange`
   `Sam           orange`
   `Sam           orange`
   `Tom           apple`
   `Tom           banana`
   `Tom           banana`
   `Tom           orange`

I want to see my result as:

**`persons   |   fruits`**
   `David        apple`
   `Sam          orange`
   `Tom          banana`

I tried using count and max functions and group by, but was not able to get right result.

Comment: please remove postgres from your tags and description redshift<>postgres!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (person) person, fruit
from (select person, fruit, count(*) as cnt
      from personfruits pf
      group by person, fruit
     ) pf
order by person, cnt desc;
```

You can write this without the subquery as well:

```
select distinct on (person) person, fruit
from personfruits pf
group by person, fruit
order by person, count(*) desc;
```

However, that is a bit hard to follow for someone not really familiar with `distinct on`.

Comment: ERROR: SELECT DISTINCT ON is not supported Location: File: /home/ec2-user/padb/src/pg/src/backend/parser/parser_gram.y, Routine: isPufnError, Line: 13328
  Server SQLState: 0A000

Comment: I got the above error. Sorry, I am querying redshift database. Since it is similar with postgres, my title has postgres. is it because of redshift ?

Comment: @LokTam . . . Yes, the issue appears to be RedSit.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want to see which fruit occurs most often, per person.  If that's correct, this should work

```
SELECT persons, fruits
FROM (
  SELECT 
    persons, 
    fruits,
    RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY persons ORDER BY FruitCount DESC) AS FruitRank -- Rank fruit count per person
  FROM (
    SELECT 
      persons, 
      fruits, 
      count(*) FruitCount -- get # rows per (person, fruit) combination
    FROM MyTable
    GROUP BY persons, fruits
  ) src
) src
WHERE FruitRank = 1 -- Return fruit with largest FruitCount, per person
```

Comment: No prob bob :) .